# Run Blender from python script

Tags: python, bash, blender

I am trying to learn how to run blender commands from external python script, I am reading this tutorial from [GitHub](https://github.com/njanakiev/blender-scripting). However when I run the first test `blender -b -P run_script.py` I get the following error message:

```
Read new prefs: /home/sim/.config/blender/2.76/config/userpref.blend

RNA_def_property_ui_text: 'option_extra_vgroups' '' description ends with a '.' ! RNA_def_property_ui_text: 'option_index_type' '' description ends with a '.' !

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/sim/Desktop/WebApp/Blender/blender-scripting-master/run_script.py", line 22, in <module>
    exec(compile(open(file).read(), scriptFile, 'exec'))

  File "fisher_iris_visualization.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Then Blender quit

Do you have any idea to solve that?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Blender includes an interpreter, python console, and scripting window.  ( https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/scripting/index.html ).  I highly recommend you try using Blender's internals unless you have a specific use case otherwise.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. The whole story comes from the fact that I need to convert a vtk file into json file in the back-end of a server (e.g subprocess). Therefore, I would like to create a script I can call and run from remote. Are there any link of reference for that ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you didn't import `numpy` module in your script.

It is my guess, without any code, it is not easy for me to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't look like you have the numpy library installed on your system.

can you verify with;

```
python -c 'import numpy; numpy.test()'
```

if it errors out then install numpy with

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

or

```
pip install --user numpy
```